# JQuery: issues with activating and disactivating a sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

I am building a menu, it has sub menus that slides down when you hover over the parent item and stays down when you click an arrow next to the parent. I got the hovering part working but when i click the arrow and leave the 'active aria' of the parent it dosen't stay down.

The `.click()` function itself shoulden't be the problem because it changes the class and prints the log.

After some reading I thought that the `.off()` function would work but it dosen't seem to...

HTML

```html
<ul id="menu-nav" class="main-navigation">
 <li class="menu-item">item 1</li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">Item 2
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li class="menu-item">Item 2.1</li>
   <li class="menu-item">Item 2.2</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="sub-menu-arrow">
   ::after
  </span>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item">Item 3</li>
 <li class="menu-item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```js
function menu_slide_toggle() {
  $('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
}

$('.menu-item-has-children').hover( menu_slide_toggle );

$('.sub-menu-arrow').click(function(event) {
  $('.sub-menu-arrow').toggleClass('active');
  $('.sub-menu-arrow').toggleClass('inactive');

  if ($('.sub-menu-arrow').hasClass('active')) {
    console.log('active');
    $('body').off( 'hover', '.menu-item-has-children', menu_slide_toggle );
  } else {
    console.log('inactive');
    $('body').on( 'hover', '.menu-item-has-children', menu_slide_toggle );
  }
});
```

If you need any other code then this I'll be happy to post it to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason it didn't work!

you can't use the `.off()` or `.on()` functions with `'hover'` you need to use `'mouseenter mouseleave'` instead. And I changed the selector from the `body` to the item which has the hover applied.

So the code that worked was:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').off('mouseenter mouseleave', menu_slide_toggle);
```